# Datatables Individual column searching (select inputs) Reloading After ajax

Tags: datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a Data table populated using ajax request then the Individual column searching (select inputs) api is called and i am able to use the search functionality,But on new data get appended to table the select feilds are not getting reinitilised and the select feild options still shows the old values

Answer (score 0):

if you update by javascript function then try this

```
function updateTable(){
    //your updation code
    var table = $("#dataTable").DataTable(); // get api instance
    // load data using api
    table.ajax.url(ajax_source).load();
};
```